# Why is Autobahn Twisted Websocket server is not completing handshake with javascript client?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I'm trying to use a twisted websocket server and connect it to a javascript client on localhost, not through a network. The server and client see each other but they can't complete the handshake. Yes I'm using a Hixie-76 wrapper provided by txWS because of a systems requirement.

I'm stumped on why they can't connect?

Version: autobahn 0.16, twisted 0.16.3

This is an actual example of what I'm trying to achieve: 
https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo using the server.py and client.html

Log:

```
2016-08-24 15:44:33+0100 [-] Log opened.
2016-08-24 15:44:33+0100 [-] WebSocketServerFactory (WebSocketFactory) starting on 8080

2016-08-24 15:44:33+0100 [-] Starting factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WebSocketServerFactory object at 0x00000000031DB7F0>

2016-08-24 15:44:33+0100 [-] Starting factory <txws.WebSocketFactory instance at 0x0000000002FA82C8>

2016-08-24 15:44:34+0100 [MyServerProtocol (WebSocketProtocol),0,127.0.0.1] Starting HyBi-00/Hixie-76 handshake

2016-08-24 15:44:34+0100 [MyServerProtocol (WebSocketProtocol),0,127.0.0.1] Completed HyBi-00/Hixie-76 handshake

2016-08-24 15:44:39+0100 [-] WebSocket connection closed:
2016-08-24 15:44:39+0100 [-] False
2016-08-24 15:44:39+0100 [-] 1006
2016-08-24 15:44:39+0100 [-] connection was closed uncleanly (peer did not finish (in time) the opening handshake)
```

Python Class:

```
from txws import WebSocketFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol

import json
import sys

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        print "Message Received!!!!"
        msg = json.dumps({'status':'PLEASE WORK'})
        self.sendMessage(msg, isBinary=False)

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print "WebSocket connection closed: "
        print str(wasClean)
        print str(code)
        print str(reason)

def make_server():
    print 'Making ws server'
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://127.0.0.1:8080")
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
    reactor.listenTCP(8080, WebSocketFactory(factory)) #txWS WebSocketFactory wrapper
    reactor.run()
```

Javascript:

```
function ConnectWebSocket() { 
    websocket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080');
    websocket_open = true;

    websocket.onopen = function(e) { 
        console.log('opened');
        console.log(e);
        websocket.send('slow test'); 
    };
    websocket.onclose = function(e) { 
       console.log("Connection closed.");
       websocket_open = false;
       websocket = null;
        ConnectWebSocket();
    };
    websocket.onmessage = function(e) { 
        console.log('message');
        console.log(e.data);
    };
    websocket.onerror = function(e) { 
        console.log('error');
        console.log(e);
    };
}
ConnectWebSocket();
```

Comment: The only thing that I can see that might be an issue is the "u" is missing in `(u"ws://127.0.0.1:8080")`  This just marks the string as unicode, and from my understanding isn't usually a big deal.  I've never used a Hixie-76 wrapper, so I'm guessing `WebSocketFactory(factory)` is where the issue is because everything else looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the issue.  As Michael S suggested it is probably in the Hixie-76 wrapper, it was.  The dev must have let that protocol slip over time and it no longer is working.  I could confirm this by tracing it back in the code.  I will report it back to the dev of txWS.

I found an alternate solution to the Hixie-76 problem.  I switched wrappers to txWebSockets at https://github.com/gleicon/txwebsockets.  Not as elegant a solution but it now works.